# Crop image using CSS whe using relative and absolute position

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CS([Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hxdhv147/5/)):

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
}

div.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

em.brand img {
  display: block;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
}

ul.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

em {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  right: 0;
}

.slides {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.slide .frame img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slide .text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide .text h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.slide .text p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <em class="brand">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40?text=LOGO"/>
        </em>
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="frame">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/675/nature/1" />
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Our Message</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  Main content
</main>
```

The logo and menu are on left and right both on top of image.
Message and caption and centered on top of image ...

So far so good. But in some screen sizes I need to crop the image.

I do it placing the image in a DIV with negative margins ([Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hxdhv147/3/)):

```
<div class="frame">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/675/nature/1" />
</div> 

.slide .frame {
  margin: -20px 0;
}
```

The problem is, as you can see in the online example, the logo, main content and menu are moved ...

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: What is the effect you're ultimately trying to achieve/problem you're trying to solve with the image cropping? Why does your first fiddle not work for you? Or why does G-Cyr's answer not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the image in CSS using the

```
background-image:url('...')
```

property. Then you can crop it with the

```
background-size: 999px ... ;
```

attribute.

Comment: The reason why I am not using background-image is because each slide will have a message and caption associated to it and I wanted to have that reflected on the markup for easier maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

If I think better of your problem you have to set the margin `.slide .frame img` or you can use this image within CSS `background-image:url('...')`

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
}

div.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

em.brand img {
  display: block;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.menu li {  
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
}

ul.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

em {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  right: 0;
}

.slides {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.slide .frame img {  
  margin: -20px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide .text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide .text h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 8px;
 }
 
.slide .text p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
 } 

main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <em class="brand">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40?text=LOGO"/>
    </em>
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="frame">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/675/nature/1" />
      </div>      
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Our Message</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  Main content
</main>
```

Comment: The reason why I am not using background-image is because each slide will have a message and caption associated to it and I wanted to have that reflected on the markup for easier maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

if you to crop the image of 20px top and bottom, apply the negative margins to it and hide overflow from its parent : http://jsfiddle.net/hxdhv147/6/

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
}

div.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

em.brand img {
  display: block;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.menu li {  
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
}

ul.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

em {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  right: 0;
}

.slides {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.slide .frame {overflow:hidden}
.slide .frame  img {  
  width: 100%;
  margin: -20px 0;
}
.slide .text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide .text h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 8px;
 }
 
.slide .text p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
 } 

main {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <em class="brand">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x40?text=LOGO"/>
    </em>
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="frame">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/675/nature/1" />
      </div>      
      <div class="text">
        <h2>Our Message</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  Main content
</main>
```

note that CSS

- use to have the [`clip();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) rules to crop content.
- but now i would advise [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) about image

Comment: I was considering object-fit but it is now supported by a few browsers which I need to support

Comment: @MiguelMoura okay , and what about the negative margins applied to the image ? ... object-fit would require a set height which you do not have here, so would clip()  too to set the clipping coordonates. it was not a proposition  but extra infos. :)